# Applying a filter after a service in Finagle

Tags: scala, finagle

I am able to apply all kind of pre-processing of incoming HTTP requests by adding filters **before** a HTTP service with `filter1 andThen httpService` 
i.e.

```
val addRequestHeaderFilter = new SimpleFilter[Request, Response] {
    def apply(req: Request, service: Service[Request, Response]) = {
      req.headerMap.add("header1","header_value")
      service(req)
    }      
 }
 Http.serve(":5000", addRequestHeaderFilter andThen theActualHTTPService)
```

The problem is, I want to add headers to the Response. Is there a post-service filter?
You can't really do `service andThen service`.

Answer (score 4):

My fault: I was reasoning about filters like they were streams. So this works:

```
val addRequestHeaderFilter = new SimpleFilter[Request, Response] {
    def apply(req: Request, service: Service[Request, Response]) = {
      val respFuture = service(req)
      respFuture.map(_.headerMap.add("header1","header_value"))
      respFuture
    }      
 }
 Http.serve(":5000", addRequestHeaderFilter andThen theActualHTTPService)
```

In the fitler, I'm applying the service and manipulating its response before returning it. And this behaves like a pre-service filter, that is, no need to invert the `andThen` functional composition.

Finagle is really cool <3